# MySQL Query - help with selection

Tags: mysql, drupal

What I'm trying is to get all users that don't have a value set for fid = 13 or no value at all in profile_values. I'm guessing this have an easy solution, ...but I just don't see it. Any help or a point in the right direction is greatly appreciated.

(The tables users and profile_values are both from Drupal.)

Simplified values:

```
uid   name  fid     value
1   user1    1       foo
1   user1    2       foo
2   user2    12      
2   user2    13      1265662514
3   user3    NULL    NULL
4   user4    NULL    NULL
```

What I was trying:

```
SELECT u.uid, u.name, pv.fid, pv.value
FROM users u 
LEFT JOIN profile_values pv ON pv.uid = u.uid  
WHERE u.status != 0
AND (pv.fid != 13 OR pv.fid IS NULL) 
GROUP BY u.uid

uid     name      fid     value
1     user1     1       foo
2     user2     12      foo 
3     user3     NULL    NULL
4     user4     NULL    NULL
```

My problem is user2 which shouldn't be there since it has a value in fid = 13

---

Thanks for all the unbelievable fast and qualified answers, cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to add an AND clause:
    AND u.uid NOT IN (select uid from profile_values where fid=13) as bad_uids

Comment: this wouldn't work. take a look about my and Anthony discussion below

Comment: Actually, this seems to work combined with OR (pv.fid = 13 AND pv.value = '') ...unless I'm overlooking something

Comment: @Borgenk: why not mine? ;-) have you tried look at this proposal EXPLAIN? ;-)

Answer (score 1):

WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM profile_values pv WHERE pv.uid = u.uid AND pv.fid = 13)

this is actually a slow solution but i cannot realize any other way

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try

```
AND (pv.fid != 13 OR pv.value IS NOT NULL)
```

?

Your conditions are little unclear:

> get all users that don't have a value set for fid = 13 or no value at all in profile_values

This means "get all users with fid equal to something other than 13 AND with some value in profile_values"?

Comment: and this will select user2 - 12, because 12 != 13 and 12 IS NOT NULL

Comment: Oh sorry, I was looking at the wrong part of the question. Why does user2 show up twice? Not having unique id's is a problem in itself, right?

Comment: nope, wrong. the first table at question is a parameters table. 1 row per each parameter. so if user have N parameters - he will have N rows in that table. and while selecting if user have fid = 13 then we have to exclude entire user from query result.

Answer (score 0):

You want only the profiles where the value is NOT blank and the fid is not 13, right? So that means if both are true OR if either are true, skip those records. So don't group them together and use the OR. Use and:

```
WHERE 
u.status != 0
AND 
pv.fid != 13 
AND
pv.fid IS NOT NULL
```

OR

```
WHERE 
u.status != 0
AND 
pv.fid IS NOT (13 OR NULL)
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2225622/mysql-query-help-with-selection/2225646#2225646 - look at my comment there